# How do we find $P(Z > -1.40)$?

Tags: normal-distribution

Can we simply do $P(Z \le 1.4)$ ?

I'm confused because in cases like  
$P(-1.4 < Z < 1.63)  = P(Z < 1.63) + P( Z < 1.4) - 1$

Why do we subtract one in the second case?

This is the case for $Z \sim (0, 1)$

Comment: What's is the distribution of random variable $Z$?

Comment: edited the post

Comment: Assuming $Z$ is the standard normal distribution, yes.  $\Pr(Z>-1.4)=\Pr(Z\leq 1.4)$ and this can be found in a table or by performing the integration by calculus as usual.

Comment: As for why subtract $1$ in the other case.  Recall that $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$, or rearranged, $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cup B)$.  Letting $-1.4<Z$ be the event $A$ and $Z<1.63$ be the event $B$... the union of these events covers everything and so occurs with probability $1$, hence $1$ is what was subtracted.

Answer (score 2):

Strating from @Александр Пальма's answer,
$$\mathbb{P}[Z\leq a]=\int_{-\infty}^{a}f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac{x^{2}}{2} \right)dx=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$ the error function being available is most environments.

You could also use the approximation proposed by  Sergei Winitzki
$$\text{erf}(t)\sim\text{sgn}(t)\sqrt{1-\exp\left(-t^2\,\frac{\frac{4}{\pi }+\alpha t^2}{1+\alpha t^2} \right)}\quad \text{with} \quad \alpha=\frac{8 (\pi -3)}{3\pi (4-\pi )  }$$ with $a=1.4$, this would give $0.919353$.

Answer (score 1):

If $Z\sim Normal(0,1)$ so we can see by symmetry $$\mathbb{P}[Z>-1.40]=\mathbb{P}[Z\leq 1.40]$$
or $$\mathbb{P}[Z>-1.40]=1-\mathbb{P}[Z\leq -1.40]$$then you can use the table or
the definition.

---

Note that $$\mathbb{P}[Z\leq 1.40]=\int_{-\infty}^{1.40}f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{1.40}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac{x^{2}}{2} \right)dx=0.919243.$$

Also, you can use the [online-calculator](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html).